# android - Using a variable from one view file in another

Tags: android, variables, view

I have two views, and I want to access the data stored in a variable in View A and pass it in View B.

How would I do that?

Thanks,

Comment: could you explain more ? Your code, your pattern ?

Comment: In View A I have a variable containing points, and I am animating that Path from those points in View B. But I need to access the variable in View A which has the points to animate in View B.

Comment: what view you are using for A and B??

Comment: Can't u able to use TextView??

Comment: No, not for an animation

Comment: Are both view is in same layout??

Comment: Yes, also in the same xml

Comment: Please explain what you want to do??  In Detail....

Comment: I want to access one view class' variable in another view class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magical way,

```
ViewA va = ...;
ViewB vb = ...;
...
vb.setData(va.getData());
```

You have to set the data from `ViewA` into `ViewB`. Alternatively, you could use a listener pattern to have `ViewA` notify `ViewB` when the data changes,

```
interface ViewADataListener {
  void onDataChanged(Data d);
}

class ViewB implements ViewADataListener { ... }

ViewA va = ...;
ViewB vb = ...;
...
va.setDataChangedListener(vb);
```

Then somewhere in `ViewA`'s implementation it must call the listener method on `ViewB`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using interface.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       ViewA viewA = new ViewA();
       ViewB viewB = new ViewB();
       viewB.setViewA(viewA);
   }

   class ViewA {
       private Object mData;

       public Object getData() {
           return mData;
       }
   }

   class ViewB {
       ViewA mViewA;

       public void setViewA(ViewA viewA) {
           mViewA = viewA;
       }

       private void test() {
           if (mViewA != null) {
               Object obj = mViewA.getData();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Make View A as a Variable in View B.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       ViewA viewA = new ViewA();
       ViewB viewB = new ViewB();
       viewB.setCallBack(viewA.getCallBack());
   }

   interface DataCallBack {
       Object getData();
   }

   class ViewA {

       private Object mData;

       private DataCallBack mCallBack = new DataCallBack() {
           @Override
           public Object getData() {
               return mData;
           }
       };

       public DataCallBack getCallBack() {
           return mCallBack;
       }
   }

   class ViewB {
       DataCallBack mDataCallBack;

       public void setCallBack(DataCallBack callBack) {
           mDataCallBack = callBack;
       }

       private void test() {
           if (mDataCallBack != null) {
               Object obj = mDataCallBack.getData();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

3./4./5....

Just FYR.
For there exists thousands of way to solve your problem.